# How to pass value to setPropertyActionListener in remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to assign a dynamic value to `#{viewScope.newLOBType}` using `setPropertyActionListener` in the `remotecommand` (shown below), so how do I pass the value from Javascript to here ?

**Code:**

```
<p:remoteCommand name="showPanel" update=":createLOBPanel">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewScope.newLOBType}" value="..<dynamic value from JavaScript>.. "/>
</p:remoteCommand>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be :

define

```
<h:inputText id="myHiddenValue" style="display:none" value="#{viewScope.newLOBType}"/>
```

then set its value using js or jquery `$("#myHiddenValue").val("wooot");`

then

```
<p:remoteCommand process="myHiddenValue" name="showPanel" update=":createLOBPanel">
```

Comment: @mohsinazeem, If you know a better way feel free to share it with the others, you are welcome.